# Spyder changes working directory (wdir) when running a script

Tags: python, spyder

When running a certain script, `Spyder` always changes the working directory (`wdir`) away from the set global working directory.

I recently migrated my data to a `new_user` and `Spyder` works fine except for one script which always changes the `wdir` to the `old_user` home directory when running the code.

```
In [1]: runfile('/home/new_user/SPYDER/test.py', wdir='/home/old_user/SPYDER')
```

I had already checked:

- Global working directory drop down menu on the console
- Python Path manager
- Preferences -> Global working directory settings
- Spyder Run location
- Script location
- That there were no other old versions of Spyder installed (i.e. on
  the other user that it may be defaulting to)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue turned out to be the run settings:

**Preferences -> Run -> General Settings -> Default Working Directory**

This was still set to the `old_user` home directory, and not the new user. I don't know why this didn't affect other scripts (or why it was still set to the old user) but, when this was changed to `new_user`, it worked fine and ran with the correct `wdir`.